# Proportionally decrease 3 numbers by n percent

Tags: percentages, ratio

I have 3 numbers 5, 90, 60, that gives = 155, I need to decrease them by n percent, so they together give 100, but to keep the ratio between them. Not sure is it even possible, any feedback would be great. 
So

```
a = 5
b = 90
c = 60
```

How much in percent, I should decrease each number so they give 100, but to keep ration as it is now.

Thank you.

Comment: Divide each number by $155$ so that they sum to $1$, then multiply by $100$ using the unit method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First keep in mind that if you decrease each number by the same percentage, their ratio remains same.

$$a \rightarrow a- \frac{na}{100}$$
and 
$$b \rightarrow b- \frac{nb}{100}$$
$$\implies \frac ab=\frac{a-\frac{na}{100}}{b- \frac{nb}{100}}=\frac ab$$

Now, for your problem, you must have,
$$\left(a- \frac{na}{100}\right)+\left(b- \frac{nb}{100}\right)+\left(c- \frac{nc}{100}\right)=100$$
plug in the values of $a,b,c$ and you can find $n$

Comment: Thank you, I like your answer, it is a nice way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{155-100}{155} = 0.3548$$
As the overall sum needs to reduce by 34.58%,  we need to reduce each number by 35.48%.